# How to recreate LinearLayout Views after rotation?

Tags: java, android, android-savedstate

Everything compiles fine, no Runtime errors, everything works as expected, but as soon as the emulator phone is rotated, all but the first View (`Button createBtn = new Button(this)`) dissapear. I'm using `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState`.

I have an activity where Views are created dynamically, using `ScrollView` and `LinearLayout`, including the first View, the create Button. The activity creates an instances of an ArrayList, which by than again get added to an extension of ArrayList-Object which implements `Parcelable`:

`private ArrayList<VocCard> mVocCardList;`

is added to

`public class VocCollection extends ArrayList implements Parcelable`'s instance

`private VocCollection mListCollection;`

Actually, `mVocCardList` is overwritten and added to the `mListCollection` everytime the create Button is clicked, but it doesn't matter since it's still possible to get the size of `mListCollection` before adding a new element to the list. `createBtn.setOnClickListener` also creates a pair of new  Views, which are named after the amount of elements in `mListCollection`.

At least, the new Views which are created after the rotation still follow the naming rule, which means that `mListCollection` could be saved within the method.

To be honest, I'm not really satisfied with the implementation using `ScrollView` and `LinearLayout`, but it took me quite some time to figure out a way to 1) create Views dynamically within an activity, and 2) to find a way to save complexer data in a `Bundle`(that's why I made an implementation of `Parcelable`).

Here is some code from said activity:

```
public class LoadActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String STATE_COLLECTION = "state_of_voc_collection_list";
    private VocCollection mListCollection;
    private ArrayList<VocCard> mVocCardList;
    private LinearLayout ll;
    private ScrollView scrl;
    ...
    ...

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            // Restore value of List from saved state
            mListCollection = (VocCollection) savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(STATE_COLLECTION);
        }

        scrl = new ScrollView(this);
        ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        scrl.addView(ll);

        Button createBtn = new Button(this);
        createBtn.setText("Create");
        ll.addView(createBtn);

        //Add for each element from mListCollection 2 Views to the LinerarLayout ll
        if(mListCollection == null){
            int count = 0;
        }else{
            int count = mListCollection.size();
            for(int i = count; i<count; i++) {
                TextView tv = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                tv.setText("saved Voc List " + (i + 1));
                ll.addView(tv);
                Button btn = new Button(getApplicationContext());
                btn.setText("Start saved Voc List " + (i + 1));
            }
        }
        ...
        ...

        createBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                //Create VocCards and add to List
                mVocCardList = new ArrayList<>(3);
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                    mVocCardList.add(new VocCard(voc_f[i], voc_n[i]));
                }

                int count = 0;
                if(mListCollection != null){
                    count = mListCollection.size();
                    mListCollection.add(mVocCardList);
                }else{
                    mListCollection = new VocCollection();
                    mListCollection.add(mVocCardList);
                }

                TextView tv = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                tv.setText("new Voc List "+(count+1));
                ll.addView(tv);
                Button btn = new Button(getApplicationContext());
                btn.setText("Start new Voc List "+(count+1));
                ll.addView(btn);

            }
        });
        this.setContentView(scrl);
    }
    ...
    ...

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Save the current List state
        savedInstanceState.putParcelableArrayList(STATE_COLLECTION, (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) mListCollection);

        // call the superclass so it can save the view hierarchy state
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }
    ...
    ...

    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Always call the superclass so it can restore the view hierarchy
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        //Restore the VocList List
        mListCollection = (VocCollection) savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(STATE_COLLECTION);
    }
}
```

and the code of `VocCollection`, as suggested:

```
package com.dede123.smartcards.vocdata;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

import com.dede123.smartcards.VocCard;

import java.util.ArrayList;

@SuppressLint("ParcelCreator")
public class VocCollection extends ArrayList implements Parcelable {

    protected VocCollection(Parcel in) {        }

    public static final Creator<VocCollection> CREATOR = new Creator<VocCollection>() {
        @Override
        public VocCollection createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new VocCollection(in);
        }

        @Override
        public VocCollection[] newArray(int size) {
            return new VocCollection[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    }

    public VocCollection(){  }
}
```

Comment: please add code of `VocCollection`.

Comment: you can add android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
into your activity tag in the Manifest file. it will handle this

Comment: Thanks, Thunder, it worked! Is there a way to add that code to the application as one istead of adding it to every activity?

Comment: I added VocCollection, Hong Duan